# Replace instead of append based on user input?

Tags: javascript, input, replace

This function currently works for appending an img in a div. But I need a replace method instead of multiple img divs stacking on top of each other.

I'm open to solutions in jQuery as well.

```
function getImg(){

    var url=document.getElementById('txt').value;
    var div=document.createElement('div');
    var img=document.createElement('img');

    img.className="img-responsive";

    img.src=url;

    div.appendChild(img);

    document.getElementById('gif-btn').innerHTML=""; <!-- Correct answer -->
    document.getElementById('gif-btn').appendChild(div);

    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help. Much appreciated!

Comment: To replace you just remove the old image after appending the new one.

Comment: There's actually a `replaceChild` method in javascript that seems to fit the bill ?

Comment: Change your `.appendChild()`s to `.innerHTML= 'stuff'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you append, you can clear out the div, then append the new one

```
function getImg(){

    var url=document.getElementById('txt').value;
    var div=document.createElement('div');
    var img=document.createElement('img');

    img.className="img-responsive";

    img.src=url;

    div.appendChild(img);

    document.getElementById('gif-btn').innerHTML = ""; // <-- Clears the gif-btn div
    document.getElementById('gif-btn').appendChild(div);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This works! More importantly, it makes sense. Learning!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
var url = $("#txt").val();
var image = $("<img>").attr("src", url).addClass("img-responsive");
var container = $("<div></div>");

// add the image to the <div> container
container.append(image);
// set the contents of gif-btn
$("#gif-btn").html(container);
```

... or better yet, you could do a simple fade-out, fade-in...

```
// replace the last line with this
$("#gif-btn").fadeOut("fast", function() { 
  $("#gif-btn").html(container); $("#gif-btn").fadeIn(); 
});
```